# Rotating a css element about an axis

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to rotate an image using css. I know how to rotate it about the x,y, and z axis, my problem is that I would like to rotate it in a diagonal way. Is there a way I can transform the y axis in such a way that I can then transform my image in a diagonal manner?

Comment: Please show how you implement the rotation around x and y axes so that we can discuss the needed rotation

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal using rotate3d

```
transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 45deg);
```

The axis of rotation is defined by an [x, y, z] vector and pass by the origin (as defined by the transform-origin property)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for the `skew` function?
[Skew function on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew)

Quick example: 
`transform: skew(15deg, 15deg);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `rotate3d`. Make sure the `z` is equal to `0` and `|x|=|y|` to have a diagonal

```css
img {
  animation:move 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move{
  from {
    transform:rotate3d(1,-1,0,0);
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate3d(1,-1,0,360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/200/200" >
```

Another diagonal. Doesn't matter how big the number you use inside `x` and `y` as long as they are equal:

```css
img {
  animation:move 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move{
  from {
    transform:rotate3d(-5,-5,0,0);
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate3d(-5,-5,0,360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/200/200" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below links. It's the same as what you want. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#matrix
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale